# Custom error for checkout required fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The default error for Woocommerce's required fields on the checkout page is this:
[image]
I'd like, to customise the error messages, so that each message displays above its field:
[image]

How can I customise the checkout page thus?

I'd need to intercept the error message, and display my own. Shouldn't be too hard, but I'm having difficulty. The main template for the checkout page is `woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php`.

Comment: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".BILLING SUBMIT BUTTON CLASS").click(function(e){
     $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
            inputss =  $(".woocommerce-invalid input");
            jQuery('.form-row').removeClass('field--error');
            jQuery('.form-row p.field__message').remove();

            $.each(inputss, function(xn, it){

                var fieldName= jQuery(it).attr('name');
                //console.log(fieldName);
                switch(fieldName) {
                    case 'billing_email':
                       jQuery(it).parent().addClass('field--error').append('<p class="field__message field__message--error" id="error-for-email">Please enter a valid email address</p>');
                    break;
                    case 'billing_first_name':
                        jQuery(it).parent().addClass('field--error').append('<p class="field__message field__message--error" id="error-for-first_name">Please enter your first name</p>');
                    break;
                    case 'billing_last_name':
                        jQuery(it).parent().addClass('field--error').append('<p class="field__message field__message--error" id="error-for-last_name">Please enter your last name</p>');
                    break;
                     case 'billing_address_1':
                        jQuery(it).parent().addClass('field--error').append('<p class="field__message field__message--error" id="error-for-address1">Please enter your address</p>');
                    break;
                     case 'billing_city':
                        jQuery(it).parent().addClass('field--error').append('<p class="field__message field__message--error" id="error-for-city">Please enter your city</p>');
                    break;

                    default:
                        //code block
                }


            });
        });

 }
```

add some style to the error class.

```
.field--error .field__message--error {
 display: block;
 }
.field__message--error {
  display: none;
  line-height: 1.3em;
   margin: 0.75em 0 0.25em;
  color: #ff6d6d;
 }
.field__message {
  font-size: 0.85714em;
 }
```

Comment: That works, but it’s not what I wanted. I was hoping for a PHP solution rather than a query one